# How to get the count of the modal value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-10

I have calculated the modal value of a column in a JOIN.

```
mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col) AS modal_col
```

I would also like the frequency of the modal value. i.e. how often does this value appear?

I have tried to simply nest this in the count function, but postgres does not allow this.

```
count(mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col))
```

`ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested`

I have also tried:

```
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY count(*)
```

I have also tried the RANK() function, but these simply give me the row numbers

I would like a simple count of the occurrence of modal value.

**Input**

| id | col |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | a |
| id1 | a |
| id1 | b |
| id2 | a |
| id2 | a |
| id3 | a |
| id3 | b |
| id3 | c |
| id3 | c |
| id3 | c |
| id3 | c |

**Output**

| id | col_mode | mode_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | a | 2 |
| id2 | a | 3 |
| id3 | c | 4 |

**EDIT**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (t1.id)  
        t1.id,
        mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.col) AS modal_col,
        count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.id, t2.col) AS mode_count
FROM    schema.foo t2
            JOIN schema.bar t1
                ON t2.id2 = t1.id2
ORDER BY t1.id, count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.id, t2.col) DESC
;
```

Thanks to Danny for the pointer.
I tried the above and postgres errors and requires that I group by both t1.id AND t2.col. Do I need to create an intermediary scratch table as I do not to want to group by both columns, just t1.id?

Answer (score 0):

```
select   distinct on (id)  
         id
        ,col                                 as col_mode
        ,count(*) over(partition by id, col) as mode_count
from     t
order by id, count(*) over(partition by id, col) desc
```

| id | col_mode | mode_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | a | 2 |
| id2 | a | 2 |
| id3 | c | 4 |

Here's another answer using `mode() within group`

```
select   id
        ,mode() WITHIN GROUP (order by col)  as col_mode
        ,max(mode_count)                     as mode_count

from
(
select   *
        ,count(*) over(partition by id, col) as mode_count
from     t
) t
group by id
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LKfcgnN2)

Comment: Thanks Danny, I have amended the question above with my attempt, and fuller query with the single inner join. It's asking me to GROUP BY two columns and not just the ID field.